# Tkinter - how to change icon color instead of using icon?

Tags: python, tkinter

instead of using a ico file or blank icon in my tkinter application, i want the tkinter icon to be a 16x16 square with a certain color.

my current code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()

icon=PhotoImage(height=16, width=16)
icon.blank()

root.wm_iconphoto('True', icon)   #New Tk 8.6 style

root.geometry('707x267')
root.title(" ")

root.mainloop()
```

how do i change the color of the icon?

Comment: I guess that creating a 16x16 image using a graphics program and setting the icon to that isn't the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own image with an image processing library, like `PIL`. First install it:

```
pip install Pillow
```

Then create a new image with:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

img = Image.new(mode='RGB',size=(16,16),color='red')
```

Now convert the image into tkinter understandable format with:

```
img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

Next, set the icon to be that new image:

```
root.wm_iconphoto('True', img_tk)
```